# Blind genius - cryptic type clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

Cryptic clue,

> Blind genius, but I heard he oiled machines? [5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be

> Leonhard EULER. He was a mathematician of great genius; he was blind; and his name is pronounced like "oiler".

Comment: Yes, good job :-)